# trying to apply style attributes on a dynamically generated html markup

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, webforms

is it a known issue / problem, not being able to use hardcoded(standard) CSS-style setting, on a dynamically (code behind) Generated Html markup ?

in a project which i am currently working on I am generating html markup ,  targeting each element of say an unsorted list items (...source being a database query results)

for illustration purpose I will just draw the idea, I think it's been done a lot...

```C#
collection = some sql query results returned  as `List<string>` type

counter  = 0

foreach item in collection 
someHtmlString = String.Format("<li  id='{0}_{1}'> {0}</li> ",  item, counter)
counter ++
```

so for each item that enters into the for/foreach loop I am *manufacturing* a specific set of css and html attributes, usually it's divided to subsets of the list-items entering the loop like you would normally in this scenario assign a class to each element, so it happens that I have that *pile* of properties,  grows as more specific design is required  and even some more.. other attributes as javascript events but mostly style,

say 10 x css properties, to set on say 3 or 4  types of setting , meaning not so fun any more seeing the foot print in my code

and one step before I can now think to just reading css-style setting from a file (using `System.IO`),  **I did try** to apply those attributes, through where they belong , in a style .css file , but as I could notes that those style properties **could not be applied** on the  generated code from  a `style.css` code/ file,  as opposed to hard-coded html markup.

so i would like to know,  what are the options if you want to avoid that bunch of lines in code behind,  other than reading it from a separated file (like coma sepertaed i could think of), then parsing it :

say a *txtfile*  -  each line is  *Property* ,  *value*.

like in a dictionary so you could read /load it straight into code from a file ,

```C#
dictionary<string, string> StyleDict = new dictionary<string, string>();

styleDict.add(styleProperty, some value);
 ...etc' (10 lines like this, x 3 or 4 times , as each could be a css class  i could use)
```

i think I ran out of ideas , what would be the proper way to apply style to a generated HtmlMarkup ?
(is it something i am doing wrong or it's a known issue?)

Comment: your question is so vague I can't believe u had three upvotes :/ am I missing something? how did you confirm that the styles could not be applied? what was the generated HTML (right-click>View page source)?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to create the html elements with inline style attributes? If this is a single list can you just add a class to your css stylesheet and assign that class to each element? `someHtmlString = String.Format("<li id='{0}_{1}' class='listItem'>{0}</li>", item, counter);`

Comment: @ZackT.
that is exactly what i was talking about it does not apply if you assign that value but as you say it should?!,  i will try to check if its a bug of a sort either VS or my Iexplorer

Comment: @Ayyash i dont unederstand what exactly is your complaint i am not english spiker though i tried my best to be clear , as for the question i was trying of corse view source seing that my code is generated properly from code behind i could see it's applying the style on each element , though trying to set class name through code behind as @ Zack  offers i already did ,  then refer that class from the style tag at the aspx page will not do the changes so is it natural or i should maybe check further why it does not aply , cause it should not happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Zack T. suggested, you can apply the styles using the method he showed :

`someHtmlString = String.Format("<li id='{0}_{1}' class='listItem'>{0}</li>", item, counter);`

Now you are complaining that these styles do not apply. For this you will need to check whether the definitions are rendered under `Style` tag inside your `Head` tag of HTML. Or the link to external `CSS` file should be placed inside your `Head` tag. Sample code snippet below

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .listItem
    {
        background-color:Red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks. the bug was me ... working too late , I was placing style in a separated file, (started separation of concerns tradition suddenly...)  though I was not trying to understand why , i jumped to conclusion for no reason(just because encountered once, an article about dynamic html controls, saying it has some issues , and I also know some things about JavaScript, that if the controls did not render yet JavaScript will not apply, unless you add defer or document ready ,etc' so i thought it is something similar)... terribly sorry

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!